# Handling large VBA collection data - procedure too large error

Tags: vba, collections

I am getting a procedure too large compiling error.

Not sure how to re-structure the following code.

Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
Dim SpamList As VBA.Collection
Set SpamList = New VBA.Collection
With SpamList
    .Add "abc@gmail.com"
    .Add "abc@aol.com"

    '...Very large list - about 5000 entries

    .Add "abc@yahoo.com"
End With

Dim z as long
For z = 1 To SpamList.Count
    If current email address is in SpamList Then
        msgbox "Spam mail!"
        Exit For
    End If
Next

Set SpamList = Nothing
```

Comment: Why do you want to hardcode your list? Wouldn't it be better to put the list in a textfile (or Excel, or database) and read it from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `With SpamList` etc. with this:

```
Dim FSO As Object
Dim fsList As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fsList = FSO.OpenTextFile("c:\spamlist.txt")
Do Until fsList.AtEndOfStream
    SpamList.Add fsList.readline
Loop
fsList.Close
```

And then move all your entries to a text file, one entry per line.